# asp.net drop down list creation in grid view

Tags: asp.net, webforms

I'm trying to create drop down list for each row on RowDataBound event. Drop down list

auto post back is enabled. When I change selection in drop down list, it doesn't go

to event.

I don't want to use javascript so looking for solution with postback.

Thanks

Comment: Your code please +gridview markup

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest you to use `Template Field` in GridView and there you can place your `drop-down List` as:

```
<asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Year">
<ItemTemplate>
<asp:DropDownList Width="50" runat="server" 
   id="ddlYear" AutoPostBack="true" 
   OnSelectedIndexChanged="ddlYear_SelectedIndexChanged">
</asp:DropDownList>
```

Then at `RowDataBound` add items to drop-downlist or bind it with some datasource.

```
protected void GridView1_RowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
    {
        //Finding the Dropdown control in the row.
        DropDownList ddlYear= e.Row.FindControl("ddlYear");
        if (ddlYear!= null)
        {
            ddlYear.DataTextField = "Name";
            ddlYear.DataValueField = "YearID";
            ddlYear.DataSource = ds.Tables["years"];
            ddlYear.DataBind();
        }
    }
}
```

You can follow the @Madhu's specified link also..

As you are doing is not good approch to add Dropdown list dynamically at `RowDataBound`  .. on every `postback` this event will recreate these drop down again.